# Question about proof verifiers like metamath.

Tags: proof-theory, automated-theorem-proving

How does metamath or other proof verifiers determine if two propositional formulas can be made equal?  Pointers to the literature would be appreciated.

Comment: Try reading coq's [source code](https://searchcode.com/file/98502169/theories/Sets/Integers.v), the low-level code refers almost directly to the axioms. Usually those proof assistants have a high-level library allowing to write things like *theorem* : $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, \exists p \text { prime}, n < p!$ together with a proof (written in high level language too), which reduces (in the engine) to low-level objects referring directly to things as the Peano axioms, allowing the software to check the correctness of the proof, and guarantee the theorem is true.

Comment: As an example, assume this is an axiom P -> (Q -> P) and the corresponding formula is A -> ((A -> A) -> A).  These can be made to match by the substitutions: P = A and Q = A -> A. What's the algorithm that does this?  I don't know where to start.

Comment: Otherwise you can declare you want to prove `A -> ((A -> A) -> A)` and provide the proof : `use  axiom P -> (Q -> P), substitution : P := A and Q := A -> A. end proof`

Answer (score 0):

Before I begin, I want to point out that most proof verifiers are very much unlike Metamath, so my answer may not apply well to the way this sort of thing is dealt with by other verifiers.

There are a few slightly different things you may be wondering about, and most (but not all) might be answered by [the Metamath book](http://us.metamath.org/#book).

#### 1. What if you have a proof to verify?

If you have a complete proof in the Metamath language (that any verifier can check), then this is a non-issue, because the proof must specify (in an indirect way that is specific to Metamath) what gets substituted for each variable.

#### 2. How do programs know without a complete proof?

Programs related to Metamath (e.g. "the Metamath program" and "mmj2") wouldn't need a complete proof to figure something like this out (or at least to narrow down the possibilities). I haven't looked through the source of either program, but I can describe one way you *could* do it, at least for the simple example included in your comment.

Since parentheses and -> are traditionally constants that cannot be replaced (substituted into), if your axiom is `P -> ( Q -> P )`, we can usually figure things out by matching up those constants. For instance, if no formula has unpaired parentheses, that would help a lot.

Even in a contrived case like `-> ( -> ( -> ( -> -> ( )` we know that P must end in `(` by looking at the end of the string, so from the beginning we know it's either `-> ( -> (` or `-> (` (as otherwise we wouldn't have the `(` before `Q` from the axiom). But the end then shows that it can't be `-> ( -> (`, so `P` must be `-> (`. That means this reduces to `P -> ( -> ( -> P )`. But then matching up the beginning and end shows that `Q` must also be `-> (`.

In a weirder case, there could be multiple options (e.g. if your axiom were `P -> Q`), but the way we usually set math up makes that rare (impossible?).

---

#### Bonus: Metamath code

For those unfamiliar with metamath, I have built an example demonstrating what I was talking about in point 2.

Let's say we have the below metamath source, which declares:

1. **c**onstant symbols that can't be substituted into
2. **v**ariables that can be substituted into
3. the types of the things that can be substituted into each variable (they all take `formula`s)
4. an **a**xiom (named "`impf`") stating that things of the form `( P -> Q )` are `formula`s
5. an **a**xiom (named "`ax`") stating that things of the form `P -> (Q -> P)` are `true`.
6. a claimed **p**rovable theorem that `A -> ( ( A -> A ) -> A )` is `true`, along with a partial proof that involves two unknown steps and then ends with an invocation of `ax`.

Then the metamath program knows that since `ax` involves the variables `P` and `Q`, which stand for formulas, the two steps better be

```
$c ( $.
$c ) $.
$c -> $.
$c formula $.
$c true $.
$v P $.
$v Q $.
$v A $.
pf $f formula P $.
qf $f formula Q $.
af $f formula A $.
impf $a formula ( P -> Q ) $.
ax $a true P -> ( Q -> P ) $.
thm $p true A -> ( ( A -> A ) -> A ) $= ? ? ax $.
```

If you load the above code (with a line-break at the end) into the metamath program, and then use the commands `prove thm` and `show new_proof /all`, it show that it knows you need to show that `A` and `( A -> A )` will need to be substituted in for the variables in the axiom, in that order (to satisfy `pf` and `qf`). Specifically, it displays:

```
1   pf=?   $? formula A
2   qf=?   $? formula ( A -> A )
3 thm=ax $a true A -> ( ( A -> A ) -> A )
```

The line of code to include the whole proof instead of the proof with unknown steps is `thm $p true A -> ( ( A -> A ) -> A ) $= af af af impf ax $.`, where the end uses [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) to tell you how to build the proof. The `af af impf` in the middle will become the needed `formula ( A -> A )` when processed.

Comment: Hi! Seeing as you are familiar with Metamath, my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3896975/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-natural-deduction-relative-to-hilbert-style-system) could use more answers, especially from your perspective.